# CefSharp.wpf and clearing the browser

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

Just getting started w/ CefSharp.wpf and I have looked thru the documentation but I have not found this (yet).  I am guessing it is there and I have just overlooked it so far.

I have been testing/playing w/ CefSharp.wpf and I am happy with how things are working.  One thing that I have noticed is if I set my browser control's Address to an invalid link, the browser control goes "blank" which I am good with relative to what I attempting.  However, if I set the the Address to an empty string, then the previous page remains on the control.  If the address is empty, is there someway to  make the browser blank like when there is an invalid address -- without assigning an invalid address?

Thanks

```
browser.Address = "www.google.com"    // Shows main Google page
browser.Address = "www.google.comm"   // Shows an empty/blank browser
browser.Address = "maps.google.com"   // Show Google Maps
browser.Address = ""                  // Continues to show Google Maps
```

Comment: Historically you'd just load about:blank

Comment: Thanks -- hadn't thought about it from that standpoint -- more of something to clear the control since the empty string/url wasn't do that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean